# drop-down menu that's moving all of the sites contents

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, units-of-measurement

so basically i want to do something like this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/czqy1jts/

**html**

```
<div id="cont1">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="footer1"></div>
        <div id="footer2">HOVER OVER ME</div>
        <div id="footer3">
            <div id="viissees"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#wrap {
  height:inherit;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;     
  bottom:0;
  background-color:purple;
}


#footer1 {
  height:10%;
  background-color:yellow;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}

#footer2 {
  height:20%;
  background-color:purple;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}

#footer3 {
  height:80%;
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

wrap inherits the height from container, whose height is set using jQuery ( window.height) 
footer1 is hidden and i use slideToggle on it.
So when someone hovers over footer2, footer1 is revealed and footer2 and footer3 drop down, making room to footer2.

But i want it to come up from the bottom, while using % for my divs. 
so i figured i set my wrapper bottom:0; and i set height:auto...

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="footer3"></div>
    <div id="footer2">HOVER OVER</div>
    <div id="footer1"></div>
</div>
```

and it works but not with percentages.
https://jsfiddle.net/nfLs1xy9/
this is acchieved using vh units, but i found out too late that the support for those are too minimal, so i thought that i should start over and try to do it with % after all. 
but i can't figure out how. i've tried all of my ideas and i'm thinking i'm running out of them. the problem is that my wrapper has to be auto and in the bottom, so that when i slidetoggle the hidden element, it makes room for the hidden element, thus shoving all of the other content upwards. but i i can't set it to auto, 'cause then my divs don't know what to base their % on.

Is this even possible?

(if my english sucked, then sorry, not my 1. language and my 1. post in stack overflow, so my appologies if i made any rookie mistakes.)

Answer (score 0):

anyway... i found a solution. i dropped the slidetoggle method and used mouseenter and mouseleave instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/4kso7125/

```
$("#footer1").hide();
var minuMeetod = function () {
    $("#footer1").show();
    $("#wrap").animate({
        bottom: "+10%"
    }, 100);
};
$("#footer2").bind("mouseenter", minuMeetod);
$("#footer1").on("mouseenter", function () {
    $("#footer2").unbind("mouseenter");
});



$("#footer3").on("mouseenter", function () {
    $("#footer2").bind("mouseenter", minuMeetod);
});
$("#footer1").on("mouseleave", function () {
    $("#footer1").fadeOut();
    $("#wrap").animate({
        bottom: "-0em"
    }, 100);
});
```

if anyone is interested, there's the solution. i basically added the menu on bottom and hid it. and then on mouseenter i just made it show ( or fadein ) and then i animated all of the content up and unbind the method, so it wouldn't start repeating its function. and then rebind it when the mouse touches the main content part. you can check the fiddle. i wouldn't be surprised if i sound little confusing. if it helps someone in the future, then yay. anyway, thanks for potential help.

Comment: Another ref, I try to draw what you want in pure HTML and CSS. See here http://codepen.io/redy/pen/EjyNXL